# How to ask questions on GitHub?

Tags: github

I am using the [Flickr4Java library](https://github.com/callmeal/Flickr4Java), which is hosted on GitHub. I have a question to the authors. On the main page it is written:

```
Comments and questions should be sent to the GitHub Repo.
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess they meant that the comments and questions should be sent to the issue tracker, in this case https://github.com/callmeal/Flickr4Java/issues.

Comment: That's what I've been using but it feel inappropriate. First, the issue tracker is like a massive forum threads that are impossible to read. Second, not all questions are about issues. More often that not, questions are just "How to configrue this?", "How to achieve that?". It should at least have a proper voting system like StackExchange

Comment: @eric I agree, not the best QA platform.

Comment: @ericn, what if you just ask on SE?

Answer (score 1):

For issues with the the code you should use https://github.com/callmeal/Flickr4Java/issues.
**However**, to reach out to the author/maintainer with something not code related or bug, you should find out if he has his email or equivalent public.

For this particular library for example, you can reach out to the author through  https://twitter.com/boncey, which is nicer than opening an issue when it's not a code issue.

Comment: In my case the author's email was available on his profile, I just had to sign into Github to reveal it!